# OutOfRangeError on FIFOQueues of different experiments

Tags: tensorflow

I am running some experiments with Tensorflow on a 4-GPU machine using CIFAR10 with the FIFOQueue implementation for input data pipeline.

I want to simultaneously run one different instance of my experiment on each of the four GPUs,
but because the data processing queues are always places on the CPU I get an OutOfRange error and
cannot run more than one instance per machine.

Is there a way to overcome this? (other than placing the data processing on GPUs)

Thanks

Comment: The reason you get this error is because you went through all the items on the queue. You could either enqueue 4x times more things on your queues, or create 4 different queues

Comment: I do want diffent queues because each experiment is using different batch sizes etc. Is there a particular way to name a queue somehow so that it's linked to the process that creared it and doesn't conflict with other experiments running?

Thanks for the help.